# How to Identify String Literals from Arrays with Regex on Java?

Tags: java, arrays, regex, string

If I have this array of Strings named tokenArray. Its contents are the following

---

[num1] [;] ["] [This] [is] [a] [\"] [string] [literal] [\"] [.] [?] ["]

---

Note: non escaped and escaped double quotation are as it is.

Question:

How do I Identify that the values between the two double quotations in the array as a single string literal?, . I'm using string concatenation to save temporary lexemes found and finally save to stack when I match is found. In my case of identifying a single line comment before it was the // and tHiS_iS_tHe_EnD_Of_NeWlInE for the start and end match. How do I apply it with regex with two double quations just like above inside that the loop in the code I put below. TIA.

Background:

It's just that the samples I am finding are in a form of single String declaration and mine was in an array. I can't quite grasp how it works with an array of strings.

BTW. I'm making a string analyzer which scan a block of code and outputs lexemes of the particular language. I already identified each lexemes  like single and block comments in addition to the delimiters and some keywords of a language without regex. But I want to try regex for the string literal that i have not detected yet. Applying the detection through if and else statement was so time consuming and confusing, but i made it through to the least.

Below is the code I am using to identifying single line comments in my array.
The for loop is my entire loop for reading my arrays and assigning newly detected lexeme to a stack.

```
 for(int ctr=0;ctr<removedNullsStackSize.length;ctr++) {   
        if(removedNullsStackSize[ctr].equals("//"))   {
            do {
                tempString = tempString + " " + removedNullsStackSize[ctr] ;
                ctr++;                   
                if(ctr>=removedNullsStackSize.length-1){
                    removedNullsStackSize[ctr]="tHiS_iS_tHe_EnD_Of_NeWlInE";
                }
            } 
            while(removedNullsStackSize[ctr]!="tHiS_iS_tHe_EnD_Of_NeWlInE");
                myQCommentsTokenized.add(tempString);
                tempString="";
        }
```

In the code above, what it does is that it concatenates the preceding arrays when it detected // and won't stop concatenating not until it detects a newline character. If a newline character is detected,it then saves it the tempstring to stack as the new lexeme found.

Comment: What is the source of this array?  Is there any chance it is JSON or another commonly-used format?

Comment: In your array definition ...{"int","num1",";",""","This",..., is there a reason the double quote isn't escaped? Should it be ...{"int","num1",";",""\","This",...  ?

Comment: Ideally you would do that already in the lexer, before the input is tokenized. Because now, you don't know how many blanks or even line breaks are between the words.

Comment: Just a typical java array. The source of the array is from multiple arrays and stacks. Much like this one, the array was formed from arrays and stacks before it that has conditions that detects keywords , identifiers etc.So I set the example array above.

I am on that part of array that has to detect string literals. I just recent found out about regex, but can't quite grasp how I will apply it with my code not unless I rewrite my entire program. :(

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. It's very unclear what's actually in the array because you've only provided a pseudo-code definition.

Comment: @Spangen, in that case no yet. Haven't thought about adding it in the lexemes yet, but  its not escaped. Because its a lexeme of the main code Im reading. eg. printf("String"); The two double quotation are as it is. The contents of the array only becomes escape when it read \" inside a string literal, much like my \n that was read as a single lexeme. I'

Comment: @JonSkeet its already that array. I just didnnnt included the single line comments part of the array since it would make the sample very long. But sure definitely works if there is a single line comment in the array. For minimalism, I remove those array of single line comments.

Comment: It's already *what* array though? It's very unclear due to the number of double quotes. What you've provided at the start certainly isn't valid Java code, so we can't take it from there. Just provide a [mcve] - it'll make it much, much simpler to help you.

Comment: okay, I'll just remove the double quotation and just make it a pseudocode syntax really. But the none escape double quotation is part of the lexeme/array. SInce I can differentiate if its an escape character or a lexeme. Its quite important for me to differentiate between escaped and non escape double quotation since that would tell me whether if its a beginining or end of a string literal. If its an escape character that it started. Then the code to execute the string literal concatenation will not be executed at all.

Comment: @Henry, thx. That's what I missed really. :(. Unfortunately I already made my own using basic loops, arrays and stacks. Now I just want to know How I could apply regex to my detected lexemes  to make it easier for me to write further code.I just can't quite rewrite the whole code again since I've already spent alot of time doing it all manually. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Pattern is.

```
//Regex for identifying string literals
         Pattern strRegex=Pattern.compile("\".*\"");

//Loop your array here to read code

//str is the temporary location of all the codes you have
//In mine, I have it inside a text area so I just typecasted it to string and start comparing there
//begins matching` for string literals that is in the strRegex
         Matcher m = strRegex.matcher(str) ;
```

After reading the code, it will then have the lexemes for the string literal in the code that was read.

```
 while (m.find()) { 
     String forReadStr=m.group(); 
     //If the end of the token is a double quote, Do this  
     //in this loop, you can then declare anything for the lexeme you detected and do anything with it
            if(forReadStr.endsWith("\"")){            
                 System.out.println(m.group()+"\n\t -> \t This is a String Literal\n");
            }
}
```